# postgresql performance joins vs plain selects

Tags: postgresql

I have a rails 3 application with 5 tables going nested at 2 levels (table1 has many > table2 has many > table 3) holding a lot of info. Think of it like a tracking system for website visitors where a lot of data gets saved and it needs to be saved fast and a lot of queries are performed when we retrieve the data for display given the counts are made to pull out the data.

I created my app without too much sql in mind at first just to get it going then I thought I'll start optimizing the db part since there will be data to work with.

I'm at the point where I have about 1 million records summed in all my tables and I thought it's time to start the optimization since I'm at 1 second response per request.

My rails app performs a query for each count without any joins involved. Just default behavior for something like user.websites.hits (which selects the user then performs another select to get the websites and for each website performs a select to get the count of visitors). In total I think it makes about 80 queries to get my page results (I know...) with everything that I need in it so I created a query which gets the all the results from a single request.

Problem is, when I run the query in my database admin it takes about 2 seconds to fetch while the page manages to execute 80 queries, load the templates and assets and render in 1.1 seconds.

I'm not a database pro but is my query bad or sometimes it's better to not use joins across multiple tables like I do. If my data continues to grow this way, will my joins query get faster or both tests will load slower?

I have indexes on all join points and WHERE fields for that query so I don't think that's the issue.

I've considered caching but I feel it's too soon for 1 mil records of small data to start doing that.

Any advices?

```
domain -> has_many: channels(we use it for split testing)
channel -> has_many: visits, visitors (unique visits by ip), sales
product -> has_many: visits, visitors (unique visits by ip), sales

The query tries to get the domains which includes:
domain_name,
channels_count,
visits_count,
visitors_count,
sales_count and
products_count via the visits table


ACTUAL QUERY:
SELECT
    domains.id,
    domains.domain,
    COUNT(distinct kc.id) AS visits_count,
    COUNT(distinct kv.id) AS visits_count,
    COUNT(distinct kv.ip_address) AS visitors_count,
    COUNT(distinct kp.id) AS products_count,
    COUNT(distinct ks.id) AS sales_count
FROM
    domains
LEFT JOIN
    channels AS kc ON domains.id=kc.domain_id
LEFT JOIN
    visits AS kv ON kc.id=kv.channel_id
LEFT JOIN
    products AS kp ON kv.product_id=kp.id
LEFT JOIN
    sales AS ks ON kc.id=ks.channel_id
WHERE
    (domains.user_id=2)
GROUP BY
    domains.id
LIMIT 20
OFFSET 0


"QUERY PLAN"
"Limit  (cost=7449.20..18656.41 rows=20 width=50) (actual time=947.837..5093.929 rows=20 loops=1)"
"  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=7449.20..20897.86 rows=24 width=50) (actual time=947.832..5093.845 rows=20 loops=1)"
"        ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=7449.20..17367.45 rows=282413 width=50) (actual time=947.463..4661.418 rows=99940 loops=1)"
"              Merge Cond: (domains.id = kc.domain_id)"
"              Filter: (kc.deleted_at IS NULL)"
"              ->  Index Scan using domains_pkey on domains  (cost=0.00..12.67 rows=24 width=30) (actual time=0.022..0.146 rows=21 loops=1)"
"                    Filter: ((deleted_at IS NULL) AND (user_id = 2))"
"              ->  Materialize  (cost=7449.20..16619.27 rows=58836 width=32) (actual time=947.430..4277.029 rows=99923 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=7449.20..16472.18 rows=58836 width=32) (actual time=947.424..3872.057 rows=99923 loops=1)"
"                          Join Filter: (kc.id = kv.channel_id)"
"                          ->  Index Scan using index_channels_on_domain_id on channels kc  (cost=0.00..12.33 rows=5 width=16) (actual time=0.008..0.090 rows=5 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Materialize  (cost=7449.20..10814.25 rows=58836 width=24) (actual time=189.470..536.745 rows=99923 loops=5)"
"                                ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=7449.20..10175.07 rows=58836 width=24) (actual time=947.296..1446.256 rows=99923 loops=1)"
"                                      Hash Cond: (ks.product_id = kp.id)"
"                                      ->  Seq Scan on sales ks  (cost=0.00..1082.22 rows=59022 width=8) (actual time=0.027..119.767 rows=59022 loops=1)"
"                                      ->  Hash  (cost=6368.75..6368.75 rows=58836 width=20) (actual time=947.213..947.213 rows=58836 loops=1)"
"                                            Buckets: 2048  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 808kB"
"                                            ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=3151.22..6368.75 rows=58836 width=20) (actual time=376.685..817.777 rows=58836 loops=1)"
"                                                  Hash Cond: (kv.product_id = kp.id)"
"                                                  ->  Seq Scan on visits kv  (cost=0.00..1079.36 rows=58836 width=20) (actual time=0.011..135.584 rows=58836 loops=1)"
"                                                  ->  Hash  (cost=1704.43..1704.43 rows=88143 width=4) (actual time=376.537..376.537 rows=88143 loops=1)"
"                                                        Buckets: 4096  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 785kB"
"                                                        ->  Seq Scan on products kp  (cost=0.00..1704.43 rows=88143 width=4) (actual time=0.006..187.174 rows=88143 loops=1)"
"Total runtime: 5096.723 ms"
```

Comment: There is a difference between running a query that joins different things and running 80 different (flat) queries. The chances are that the database (if not fooled with incorrect statistics *and* has correct indices) will *beat* locally transferring the data and performing local joins on it .. of course, this all "depends". (For instance, a single query can become super-hyper-denormalized with cross-joins pretty quickly.)

Comment: If you didn't have nested tables you would have a LOT of repeated data. Your database could be several times bigger. But if you can get the data with a plain select, why bother joining? Get just what you need, never use *. Try to keep queries to a minimum; querying the database several times is always slower than fetching a lot of data and using the system ram (or the client's ram).

Comment: Well my intention was to keep them to a minimum when I noticed that 80 queries beat 1 in terms of speed that's why the discussion.

Answer (score 3):

1 million records is not very much and joining 5 tables is a simple task for a database. Having indexes is nice, but are they usefull? What does [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html) tell you about your query? And what about configuration? The default configuration is just enough to get started, it's not a setting for the best possible performance for all types of workloads.

But don't worry about a couple of joins, relational databases are used to that.

Comment: The only thing that I changed on the db server is setting `shared_buffers` to `150MB`. Here's a paste of the query analyzed: http://pastebin.com/XB40df2X I'm not sure to be honest if the indexes are useful or not since I never had to deal with records of this amount, I'm just going by the book to say by creating indexes on joining points and such. Other than that, I'm in the dark

Comment: work_mem is too low, see the Materialize steps. Also a couple of Seq Scan's (sequential table scan of all data) that indicate that the database doesn't have usefull indexes or the query just asks for too much data from a table. Without the actual query it's hard to help you, but you do have many options to improve performance a lot.

Comment: I've updated the initial question with explain results and also the query example. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Did you change the setting for work_mem? Set it to 10MB or so and check EXPLAIN ANALYZE again. The Materialize should disappear.